# Set width property inside page.resource

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to set the width of a RichTextBlock based on whether the device is a PC or phone (UWP app), but I'm having problems getting to the property...

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="sectionTemplate">
        <common:RichTextColumns>
            <common:RichTextColumns.ColumnTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RichTextBlockOverflow Width="300" Margin="20,0,0,10"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </common:RichTextColumns.ColumnTemplate>
            <RichTextBlock Margin="10,0,10,10" TextAlignment="Justify" Width="300" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords">
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="{Binding}" />
                </Paragraph>
            </RichTextBlock>
        </common:RichTextColumns>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

Any suggestions on the easiest way to do this?

Comment: you can use converters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom device family state trigger!

[Custom state triggers on GitHub](https://github.com/dotMorten/WindowsStateTriggers).

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState x:Name="desktop">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <triggers:DeviceFamilyStateTrigger DeviceFamily="Desktop" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="richTB.Width" Value="300" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="mobile">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <triggers:DeviceFamilyStateTrigger DeviceFamily="Mobile" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="richTB.Width" Value="200" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Comment: While DeviceFamilyStateTrigger is a decent solution, you have to keep Continuum in mind. At some point in the near future your 'Mobile' app will run on a 23" screen.

Comment: I ended up having to stick it inside of a user control, but it worked perfectly! Thanks!